# Amazon EC2でアクセス制限をしたい

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-elb

ELBを使用していて、A,Bと二つのインスタンスが存在します。
DB(RDS)は同じものを使用していて、セキュリティグループは全て統一してあります。
ELBをつけていますが、A,Bでは分けていて、Bだけアクセス制限をしたいのですがうまくいかないです。
この場合は、どこの部分を設定すればいいのでしょうか？
Bのセキュリティグループだけ変更すると、DBとのセキュリティグループが合わなくなってしまいますし、A,B同じセキュリティグループで制限するとAのインスタンスもかかってしまいます。

Comment: ご質問の状況が分かりにくいです。`Bだけアクセス制限をしたいのですがうまくいかないです` とのことですが、どういった制限が必要で、どのようにうまくいかないか具体的に記述してもらえますか？

Answer (score 1, accepted):

どこから B への、どのポートへのアクセスを制御したいのか、質問文からはわかりかねますが、
A と B でアクセス制御を変えたいのであれば、ELB, A, B, DB を同じセキュリティグループ(from:自グループ、to:ALL)にするのではなく、下記URL の図のように、各レイヤでセキュリティグループを作成し、「from:上位グループ、to:サービスポート」で許可するようにします。
[CDP:Functional Firewallパターン](http://aws.clouddesignpattern.org/index.php/CDP:Functional_Firewall%E3%83%91%E3%82%BF%E3%83%BC%E3%83%B3)

その上で、「A だけのセキュリティグループ」、「B だけのセキュリティグループ」をそれぞれ用意して、個別に許可することになると思います。

あるいは、セキュリティグループではなく、B の OS 側で制限するか。

もう少し、具体例があると回答が付くと思います。